# Django management task won't work on CentOS in crontab or outside project directory

Tags: django, centos5

On my local machine (Mac OSX 10.6) I wrote a django custom admin command which works great.  I can use it both within and outside my project directory just fine.  For some reason on my CentOS 5.6 server, it won't work from outside the project directory.  This is really annoying since using this custom admin command in a cron job requires it to run from the home directory.

in short:

When I run "python ./manage.py scrape" or "python manage.py scrape", everything is fine.

When I run "python /home/[username]/webapps/myproject/manage.py scrape" or "python myproject/manage.py scrape", I get the following error:

> unknown command: 'scrape'
>
> Type 'manage.py help' for usage.

On CentOS, when I run manage.py help inside the project directory, scrape shows up as a command; but if I run it outside the project directory, scrape does not appear as a valid command. On OS-X scrape appears as a valid command regardless of where I run manage.py help from.

Any idea how I can fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I know CentOS ships with Python 2.4, so is your code running on 2.4 or are you using a contained environment, this is usually fixed by adding your PYTHONPATH correctly

```
import sys
print sys.path
```

verify such for starters

Comment: yep python2.4 is running on centOS and python2.6 is running locally. i guess this could be causing the problem, but from what i've heard python is pretty backwards compatible: http://regebro.wordpress.com/2010/02/12/yes-python-2-6-is-backwards-compatible/

however, i just noticed i'm running django1.2.1 locally and 1.3.0 on the server. could this cause problems?

Answer (score 0):

This should get you up and running: http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/374/